Georgian "suffixal nominal marker"
Let me conjugate აშენება asheneba "to build" as an example.
In the present indicative:
ვაშენებ v-a-shen-eb-Ø "I build"
აშენებ Ø-a-shen-eb-Ø "you build"
აშენებს Ø-a-shen-eb-s "he builds"
The imperfect (imperfective past) is formed nearly identically, except with the addition of an extra -d- after the thematic suffix (-eb-, in this case). Since this creates an (I assume) illegal cluster, an (I assume) epenthetic -i is added to the end of the verb - except for 3.SG, where -s is swapped out for -a instead:
ვაშენებდი v-a-shen-eb-d-i "I was building"
აშენებდი Ø-a-shen-eb-d-i "you were building"
აშენებდა Ø-a-shen-eb-d-a "he was building"
The present subjunctive is nearly identical to the imperfect, except now this post-d- vowel is forced to be -e, and the -a in 3.SG goes back to being -s:
ვაშენებდე v-a-shen-eb-d-e-Ø "I build (SBJ)"
აშენებდე Ø-a-shen-eb-d-e-Ø "you build (SBJ)"
აშენებდეს Ø-a-shen-eb-d-e-s "he builds (SBJ)"
So what I was initially taught was that v- was the 1.SG subject marker, Ø- was the 2.SG subject marker, and that -s/-a were two different allomorphs of the 3.SG subject marker (it's also -a in e.g. the aorist past:  ააშენა a-a-shen-Ø-a "he built").
I was trying to look up where the -e evolved from. What is it, exactly, diachronically? But in looking for what the relevant search term for this suffix is, I stumbled across this description on the Wiktionary Georgian verbs appendix:

The transitive verbs (which employ the v- set) use the suffixal nominal marker -s- (as in a-šen-eb-s, c̣er-s) for the third person singular in present and future screeves.  Intransitive verbs, the past and perfective screeves of the transitive and medial verbs, and indirect verbs, employ sets of vowels: in the indicative, i (strong) or e (weak) for the first/second person, o or a for the third person; in the subjunctive, the suffixal nominal marker is the same for all persons, generally e or o or, less frequently, a.  The aorist intransitive form avašene, 'I built', has the structure, a-v-a-šen-∅-e, characterized by preverb -a- and weak suffixal nominal marker -e-.

Essentially saying that there aren't two morphemes here, the 3.SG -s/-a and whatever -i/-e is supposed to be... there's one morpheme here, with four allomorphs -s/-a/-i/-e, which they're calling the "suffixal nominal marker".
I... cannot fathom why that would be the way to analyze the verb system, not least of which because it implies აშენებდეს a-shen-eb-d-e-s "he builds (SBJ)" has two copies of the same marker placed back-to-back.
But plenty of other papers seem to take it for granted that there is such a thing as the "suffixal nominal marker" slot in the Georgian verb template. For example, this, this, and this - they're not about the "suffixal nominal marker", but they all list out the verb template and give one suffix slot the name "suffixal nominal marker".
I don't understand why 1) this would be one verb category and not two separate unrelated categories (subject and... mood, I guess?), or 2) why they would be "nominal" in nature? I guess they superficially look like the nominative case allomorph -i and the dative case -s, but I don't know why you would conclude that slapping noun cases onto a verb is where these evolved from? I've been looking up "suffixal nominal markers" looking for an article to explain this but I can't find any, they all just presuppose that they exist. What am I missing here?

The verb template on the same page calls that slot the suffixal person marker, which (to someone like me who knows very little of Georgian verbs) would seem to be a more intuitive name for it, given that it seemingly marks the person of the subject/object. I have no idea how to account for the -e-s in a-šen-eb-d-e-s, though – it looks like the same slot filled twice to me as well.
